# Visual representation of the parts of a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been learning Rails for a few months now and recently realised it would be convenient if there existed some visual "map" of the parts of a Rails application. Not just the MVC parts but more nuclear bits such as partials, specs etc. This might be illustrated as several flows e.g. when a page loads and when a test is run.

Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the source code? It is well written and commented and you should be able to gain some understanding from it. Here is the code for the 3.0.9 branch https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/3-0-9

As far as visualizing your own application goes take a look at [Rails ERD](http://rails-erd.rubyforge.org/) or [Railroad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting these tools. What I'm looking for though is a very simple diagram that serves as a learning aid or cheat sheet; something less intimidating than ERD, UML and source code. I'm still a n00b but I can see massive value in uber-b00bs having a diagram that shows the MVC but also - at a glance - illustrates how the more nuclear parts fit into the scheme of things, both in terms of the directory structure and application composition. If nothing exists I'll take a stab at creating one.

Comment: And my uber-b00bs I mean uber-n00bs :/

Comment: I cant find one, if you want go ahead and take a stab at it since it seems like it hasn't been done.

Comment: Agree a visual of the parts of ROR woud be good. Some of us are more visual and I usually find diagrams cut down my learning time significantly